# Accessing HTML/JavaScript file from Jar/war file in Spring Boot using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

I am working on the Maven-based Project where I have to create a jar file that contains JavaScript file(E.g Bar chart) and in the second project, I have the Thymeleaf template, where I have to load the jar file to view the contents. Actually it is a modular-based Project.

The question is how can i load the executed jar/war file of the Maven-based project to the second Thymeleaf-based project to view the contents on it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.

I tested this two months ago and used a jar project that was shown in the image.
Basically, you should call these files from the root of the main project ex:
http://localhost:8080/project/js/bootstrap.js

I left this project public, I created exactly to test this situation, if you want, you can see it in this repo: https://github.com/e3duardo/webasset

[image: webasset]

Comment: But I want to put the jar file in the other project. The main question is how Thymeleaf will access the Js file from the jar file?

Comment: After a slight research i come up with an idea that one of the solution is Thymeleaf Template Resolver. Have you any idea about it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the repo. If i am not wrong your project cover the first part of my question and now i am looking forward for the second part solution.

Comment: yes, I never used Thymeleaf before, but if you can import that js file in somewhere, you will make it. sorry I can't help more with Thymeleaf.